# where is Fixed[Misc] font

Tags: linux, fonts

In kate (or QtCreator), I've a font named "Fixed[Misc]". I'd like to retrieve the font file(s) but I didn't find them:
in my font directory, I've a "misc" directory, but I can't find exactely the font I've in kate...

could you give me some informations on how it works and how to get the glyphs I've in kate ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed[Misc] is the default monospace font of the legacy core fonts subsystem of x-windows

You do not want to dig into this, this subsystem is a mess of legacy fonts in weird pre-opentype multi-file formats and incomplete unicode coverage which are quasi unmaintained and have been on the killing block for about a decade (and wayland/mir will finish them up soon).

I'm not sure if kate is even supposed to show you those fonts if a modern font systems like fontconfig is activated (this may be distribution dependent) but if you're only seeing core fonts in your apps you have a deployment problem because QT and KDE do know how to do better when built/deployed properly.